# re.escape returns unusable directory

Tags: python, replace, directory

using `re.escape()` on this directory:

`C:\Users\admin\code`

Should theoratically return this, right?

`C:\\Users\\admin\\code`

However, what I *actually* get is this:

`C\:\\Users\\admin\\code`

Notice the backslash immediately after C. This makes the string unusable, and trying to use `directory.replace('\', '')` just bugs out Python because it can't deal with a single backslash string, and treats everything after it as string.

Any ideas?

### Update

This was a dumb question :p

Comment: `re.escape` is not supposed to return a usable directory name. It's supposed to escape a string so that it can be matched literally in a regex. The string you get is correct and usable in a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it should not. It's help says "Escape all the characters in pattern except ASCII letters, numbers and '_'"

What you are reporting you are getting is after calling the print function on the resulting string. In console, if you type `directory` and press enter, it would give something like: `C\\:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\code`. When using `directory.replace('\\','')` it would replace all backslashes. For example: `directory.replace('\\','x')` gives `Cx:xxUsersxxadminxxcode`. What might work in this case is replacing both the backslash and colon with ':' i.e. `directory.replace('\\:',':')`. This will work.

However, I will suggest doing something else. A neat way to work with Windows directories in Python is to use forward slash. Python and the OS will work out a way to understand your paths with forward slashes. Further, if you aren't using absolute paths, as far as the paths are concerned, your code will be portable to Unix-style OSes.

It also seems to me that you are calling `re.escape` unnecessarily. If the printing the directory is giving you `C:\Users\admin\code` then it's a perfectly fine directory to use already. And you don't need to escape it. It's already done. If it wasn't escaped `print('C:\Users\admin\code')` would give something like `C:\Usersdmin\code` since `\a` has special meaning (beep).